# ¿Cómo hacer referencia a un método en aspx con c# en un js para ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax

Tengo puesto este código en mi página

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function Gurdar() {
                var actionData = " { 'nombre': '" + $("#<%=txtNombre.ClientID%>")[0].value   + "' , 'apellido': '" + $("#<%=txtApellidos.ClientID%>")[0].value + "' , 'email': '" + $("#<%=txtDireccionCorreo.ClientID%>")[0].value  + "' , 'contraseña': '" + $("#<%=txtContraseña.ClientID%>")[0].value + "' , 'numero': '" + $("#<%=txtTelefono.ClientID%>")[0].value + "'}  ";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Registro.aspx/Guardar",
                data: actionData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert("Repuesta " + response.d);
        }
```

Esto recupera los datos de un conjunto de datos y los manda a un método 
que se encuentra en c# que llama a la base de datos y agrega los datos.
Lo que quiero es hacer un archivo js para meter ese mismo método y tenerlo  todo en un archivo con exención .js

```
function GurdarAjax() {

     var parametros = {
         nombre: $("#txtNombre").val(),
         apellido: $("#txtApellidos").val(),
         email: $("#txtDireccionCorreo").val(),
         contraseña: $("txtContraseña").val(),
         numero: $("txtTelefono").val()
     };
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "Registro.aspx/Guardar",
         data: parametros,
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: OnSuccess,
         failure: function (response) {
             alert(response.d);
         }
     });
 }
 function OnSuccess(response) {
     alert("Respuesta " + response.d);
 }
```

Lo hice de esta manera y lo referencié a la página pero no efectúa nada.
Casi no sé mucho de ajax.

Comment: En tu navegador presiona la tecla F12. Revisa las pestañas "network" y "console" y revisa si hay errores. Es posible que no hayas agregado la referencia al archivo con extensión `.js`. Actualiza tu pregunta con el código de la página que usa el archivo con extensión `.js`.

Comment: podrías poner tu código de ASPx ?

Comment: Ojo con los nombres, tenías escrito `Gurdar` en lugar de `Guardar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta agregando al ASPX la siguiente referencia
`using System.Web.Services;` en tu código .cs

Tu método Guardar debe de ser estático y agregarle el atributo `[WebMethod]`

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void Guardar(string nombre, string apellido, string email, string contraseña, string numero)
    {

    }
```

Veo que tu mandas un objeto `parametros` lo cual debes de crear este objeto de lado del servidor y esperar ese objeto en el método:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void Guardar(Parametros parametros)
{

}
```

Si esto no funciona intenta agregando un asp:ScriptManager a tu HTML del ASPX y usando el Objeto PageMethods.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script>    
        var nombre: $("#txtNombre").val(),
            apellido: $("#txtApellidos").val(),
            email: $("#txtDireccionCorreo").val(),
            contraseña: $("txtContraseña").val(),
            numero: $("txtTelefono").val();

        PageMethods.Guardar(nombre, apellido, email, contraseña, numero, GuardarSuccess, OnError);

        function GuardarSuccess(data) {
            //Hacer Algo despues de guardar
        }

        function OnError(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Ten en cuenta que el código no está completo solo agrego el código necesario para explicar, por ejemplo falta la librería de JQuery, pero esto ilustra a lo que me refiero.

Espero y te sirva.